# Google Cloud SQL accessing through JAX-RS

Tags: java, rest, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

I'm building a REST api in eclipse using Jersey on google app engine.

However whenever I try and access the cloud sql I get an empty JSON array returned to me, google cloud logging gives me no error and I get a HTTP 200 when i test in a rest client.

This is returned in the rest client

```
[]
```

Here is my DAO code

```
@Override
public ArrayList<StaffInfo> getAllStaff() {

    allStaff = new ArrayList<>();


    Statement state = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;
    Connection conn = null;
    try {
        String url = null;
//          if (SystemProperty.environment.value() == SystemProperty.Environment.Value.Production) {
          Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.GoogleDriver");
          url = "jdbc:google:mysql://{app id}:staff-database/staffDatabase?user=root";
//          }
//          } else {
//            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
//            url = "jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:8888/staffdata?user=michael";
//          }
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url);


        state = conn.createStatement();
        rs = state.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM StaffTable;");
        while (rs.next()){
            String forename = rs.getString("Forename");
            String surname = rs.getString("Surname");
            String location = rs.getString("Location");
            String phoneNum = rs.getString("Phone");
            String email = rs.getString("Email");
            allStaff.add(new StaffInfo(forename, surname, location, phoneNum, email));
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (state != null){
            try {
                state.close();
            } catch (SQLException e) {}
            state = null;
        }
        if (rs != null){
            try {
                rs.close();
            } catch (SQLException e){}
            rs = null;
        }
    }

    return allStaff;
}
```

The code that invokes it

```
@GET
@Path("/getall")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public ArrayList<StaffInfo> getAllStaffDefault(){
    return staffDAO.getAllStaff();
}
```

The project structure:

[image]

Here is the database contents:

[image]

**EDIT**

So after many hours I have now got an error in google cloud logging that says:

```
org.glassfish.jersey.server.ContainerException: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure
```

After finding this error i then tried to create a connection profile in eclipse to at least try and connect to my database, more errors:

```
Could not connect to DB Connection.
```

`Error creating SQL Model Connection connection to DB Connection.         (Error: com/google/api/client/http/HttpTransport)
com/google/api/client/http/HttpTransport
Error creating JDBC Connection connection to DB Connection. (Error:     com/google/api/client/http/HttpTransport)
com/google/api/client/http/HttpTransport`

Comment: Have you verified that you have data in that database? Instead of printing the exception in your catch block, you should rethrow it so that an exception will cause the HTTP request to fail instead of returning an empty result.

Comment: Yes it is definitely in the database i have verified using sequel pro and there are 5 records in there @Vadim

Comment: Please also see my second comment. Change e.printStackTrace() to throw new RuntimeException(e). It's not a good practice to swallow exceptions. A REST API should return an error instead of en empty list on an exception.

Comment: After changing the catch block i get this error in the google cloud log org.glassfish.jersey.server.ContainerException: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure
@Vadim

Comment: Please double check if the app engine app is listed as an authorized application in the Cloud SQL instance.

Comment: Yes it is listed @Vadim

Comment: Please update your question with your findings so far. Include the full stack trace and error message.

Comment: Can you add the full stack trace? I think you only included one part of it so it's hard to see what the root cause is.